# wordpress jquery plugin goes is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this error `jQuery(...).signature is not a function`

I am creating a custom plugin form that dealing user to have a signature. but suddenly, on wordpress got this error.

I am using this jquery plugin http://keith-wood.name/signature.html

this is my code in defining:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_style_jsignature' );

function load_custom_wp_style_jsignature() {

        wp_register_style( 'ax-link-jsignature', plugins_url() . '/path/jsignature/css/jquery.signature.css');

        wp_enqueue_style( 'ax-link-jsignature' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_jsui' );

function register_plugin_jsui() {       
    wp_register_script( 'js-ui', plugins_url( '/path/ui/jquery-ui.js', __FILE__ ),array('jquery'), null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'js-ui' );

}

function register_plugin_sketch() {     
    wp_register_script( 'ax-sketch', plugins_url( '/path/jsignature/js/jquery.signature.js', __FILE__ ),array('js-ui'), null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ax-sketch' );

}
```

this is the view `<div id="axl_signature_wrap"></div>`

and the js script:

```
<script>
    var sig = jQuery('#axl_signature_wrap').signature();
    jQuery('#sig_clear').click(function() {
        sig.signature('clear');
    });
</script>
```

on my test on local html not implemented on wordpress, these code were working. I also check the console on wordpress, all the required scripts are present, I am wondering why it won't work? any ideas?

Comment: where is `s-ui` dependence for `ax-sketch` script?

Comment: Do you have a page where this example runs? There could be lots of things: your script is defined before jQuery is loaded, jQuery is not in the global scope (no window.jQuery).

Comment: I implemeted on http://stg.tide.com.au/enrolment-application/?srmsform_type=registration_only in the last part of the form, "Confirm Submission" tab.. you can check on the console

Comment: if you want to get help, you should to answer questions ;) . as I said, your dependence is broken, and your `jquery.signature.js` not loading. also, the path for css file is wrong

Comment: just fixed the script sources issues but still got this error `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).signature is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fixed your first errors. The next is that your initialization of `signature()` is starting, but the `jquery.signature.js` script not loaded yet( it's loading in the footer after your code ).

To make it work just wrap your code into some delay functions, like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var sig = jQuery('#axl_signature_wrap').signature();
   jQuery('#sig_clear').click(function() {
       sig.signature('clear');
   });
});
```

Another way to make it work is to put your code after `jquery.signature.js` in the DOM tree.